# Numpy: how to take some part of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing

I have to take only some parts/subset of a matrix that has 1273x1273 dimension.

I have two indices ={i,j}, and I have to take the elements of a matrix that have i as index of row, but not j as column, and vice versa.

for example:

```
M=[[1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8],
  [9,10,11,12],
  [13,14,15,16]]
```

If i=1 and j=3, I have to construct a submatrix that is

```
[[5,7],
[13,15]]
```

I am supposing that the first row and the first column have index=0.

Comment: so you want elements of 1st row but not from 3rd column. Your expected output must be `[5,6,8]`. What I am missing here?

Comment: @Sociopath: exactly. And vice versa would yield `[14,15,16]`

Comment: Isn't it `[5, 6, 7]` (row = 1, column != 3) and `[4, 12, 16]` (row != 1, column = 3)?

Answer (score 0):

First, fetch rows `i` and `j`.

```
# names are less than perfect
row_i = M[i]
row_j = M[j]
```

Then remove columns `j` and `i` from those rows.

```
del row_i[j]
del row_j[i]
```

Then return your new matrix (`[row_i, row_j]`.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the i or the j change as you want, but the basic thing here to extract the first 3 columns without the fourth one is:

```
m[:,:2]
```

and if you want the last column separate use:

```
m[:,3]
```

You can change the 2 to the column number you want.

Comment: > I have to take only some parts/subset of a matrix that has 1273x1273 dimension.
The matrix being worked with is much larger than the 4x4 example provided by asker (thankfully, they didn't drop the entire thing into the question body!)

Comment: he just have to change the "2" to the number of the column he want to

Comment: > he just have to change the "2" to the number of the column he want to 
That should probably be included in your answer then.